# Does QML support access specifiers like Private for properties?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I just want to know do we have any concept access specifiers like private property in QML as we have in C++.

If not if would like to know in case i have about 10 properties in my QML component but i have to limit the access to only 2 properties. how can we achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is no such builtin feature in QML itself, but here is Qt Quick Components approach:

```
Item {
  property int sum: internal.a + internal.b
  QtObject {
    id: internal
    property int a: 1
    property int b: 2
  }
}
```

Properties of 'internal' object are invisible outside of Item, but may be freely used inside of it.

Comment: is it a must to have `QtObject` or is it possible also to, for example, via this method to declare private property inside `ListView`?

Comment: You can use any element you want instead of QtObject.

Comment: From the docs: "It can be useful to create a QtObject if you need an extremely lightweight type to enclose a set of custom properties" - so using QtObject is the best thing to do for the purpose of the question here.

Comment: @FourtyTwo - yeah, extremely lightweight, only about 400-500 bytes when completely empty LOL. If there is another internal object, it would be better to use something you actually need than waste any extra memory on QtObject. On a side note, pretty silly to not have private specifier in QML, it wouldn't have been that hard to implement that feature. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60029?filter=-2

Comment: Though I like your answer since it answers the original question, I think it might be better to instead use `_` or `__` prefixes as a convention to avoid the extra overhead of having `QtObject`s in every component.