# How to encapsulate a private variable in QML of Qt5?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to make some data members in QML only accessible from the inside of the owner class. There are some [workarounds in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Private_Properties), but I don't know how to do in QML of Qt5 (Qt Quick 2). Does someone know?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does QML support access specifiers like Private for properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252158/does-qml-support-access-specifiers-like-private-for-properties)

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Thank you, I haven't found the similar question before I asked.